# Formatting footnotes with footmisc package -- get justification

Tags: formatting, footnotes, footmisc, justification

I would like to change the default format of the footnotes in order to get left-aligned text. Therefore, I am using the following code (which works fine):

```
\usepackage[hang, bottom]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
```

However, using this specification the justification gets lost (I also want right-alignment)
I already tried to use

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

and then `\justify` but this results in vertical spacing issues. I know that I could probably get rid of this with `\vspace` but I would like to implement something less dirty.

Many thanks in advance!
Katie

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your problem is. I tried this MWE

```
% footmiscprob.tex  SE 593822
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hang,bottom]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\textheight}{0.3\textheight} % make a shorter page

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems to do what you are after because the footnote is left and right justified.

Perhaps you would like to edit your question by including an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can process which shows your problem.